# How do i get the status of Paypal when it is completed

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

.I am developing a site where users can login with paypal and pay for a specific service. Money is transferring correctly. But i always get the status as `Pending`  and reason as `paymentreview` or reason as `unilateral`. Is there any way to get the status when it is `completed`. I am testing this in sandbox. my code is

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST" name="_cart" id="paypal_form">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="mybusiness@gmail.com" />
<input type="hidden" id="custom" name="custom" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="on0" name="on0" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" id="amount_1" name="amount_1" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $cntry; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Account Deposit" />
<input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="10" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="RETURN URL AFTER TRANSACTION" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="URL FOR UPDATING STATUS AFTER PAYMENT" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="MYSITE.COM" />
</form>
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) is for. You get a notice sent to you by Paypal that will notify you when you get paid or when your payment status changes. So Paypal will notify you when your payment status goes to `Completed`